# How to make an Abandoned Cart in PrestaShop

Tags: prestashop, cart

We just run into an issue and we don't find the answer for the question.
We'd like to test a function that is related to the abandoned cart status, but we don’t know how to abandon a cart, even though we put some items on the cart but it stays non ordered, and if we log out it still doesn’t update the status.

We kinda lost, and we don’t find the answer to this question. (How to abandon a cart is prestashop)

Answer (score 1):

As you may have seen from Prestashop core this is one of the functions used by it to get abandoned carts.

```
public static function getAbandonedCarts($date_from, $date_to)
{
    return Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue(
        '
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_guest)
    FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'cart`
    WHERE `date_add` BETWEEN "' . pSQL($date_from) . '" AND "' . pSQL($date_to) . '"
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders` WHERE `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders`.id_cart = `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'cart`.id_cart)
    ' . Shop::addSqlRestriction()
    );
}
```

It does perform a check inside the table "cart" about the date obviously. But, more importantly, it does check if there is a record of an order related to that entity cart. If a record in table "orders" does not exist it means we have an "abandoned cart".

You can find the above function inside the class "AdminStatsControllerCore" which is, most likely, the logic to get "abandoned carts" inside the back office (Orders -> Shopping Carts).

Hopefully, I made it more clear to you how Prestashop handles abandoned carts.

Answer (score 0):

Just older carts not converted to order appear like abandoned.

By DB, substract 1 year to your desired cart, like this:

```
UPDATE ps_cart 
SET 
date_add = date_add(date_add, INTERVAL -1 YEAR),
date_upd = date_add(date_upd, INTERVAL -1 YEAR)
WHERE id_cart = your_id_cart;
```